# Spring @Profile and autowiring matching

Tags: java, spring

I'm using Spring framework (ver 3.2) and after some refactoring in my application I've faced with the problem with Autowiring with Profile configuration.

Let say I have one interface which is implemented by two classes. These classes implements bunch of methods depending on environment settings. Actually I have 3 different profile properties profile1, profile2 and profile3. Using profiles works well but here for the first time I have a little problem because class cannot be injected due to finding 2 candidates.

```
public interface Iexample {
  public void doSomething();
}

@Profile("profile1")
public class classA implements Iexample {
  doSomething(){..}
}

@Profile("{profile2, profile3}")    
public class ClassB implements Iexample {
  doSomething(){..}
}

public class Test1 {

@Autowired
Iexample example; //Should use implementation based on profile1 or profile2

}

public class Test2 {

@Autowired
Iexample example; //Should use implementation based on profile3 only

}
```

Current property configured:

```
spring.profiles.active= profile1,profile3
```

Possible configuration

- profile1, profile3
- profile2, profile3

Is any way to specify which class should be implemented in any case (something like @Qualifier) ?

Why not @ActiveProfiles ?

> ActiveProfiles is a class-level annotation that is used to declare
>   which active bean definition profiles should be used when loading an
>   ApplicationContext for test classes.

In this case I need to know if there's any way to indicate which class depending on the profile should be injected.

Please have a look at the example below.

```
@Controller
public class exampleController {
    @Autowired
    // Suppose that this can be possible
    @Qualifier("{profile1, profile2}")
    Iexample example
}
```

If Qualifier specified in that way may work then I will be able to resolve this problem.

Thanks

Comment: Annotate your test case with @ActiveProfiles

Comment: I've updated question regarding to your comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can mark a bean with the [@Primary](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Primary.html) annotation to specify, that it should have priority as an autowire candidate. The javadoc is for Spring 4, but the documentation for Spring 3.2 also mentions that annotation.

Comment: I considered to use the @Primary annotation, however There some cases when I'm not able to determine which implementation can be default. The only place when I'm completely sure what I need is in a class where I injecting an interface. Please have a look at the comments in Test1 and Test2 class.

Anyway thanks for the hint.